# A relation between covariant derivative of two unit vector fields along a curve to the variation of angle that they form

Tags: differential-geometry

In reading Manfredo P. Do Carmos revised & updated second edition on Differential Geometry of Curves & Surfaces, I have stumbled upon a difficult proof to follow (p. 254).

> Lemma 2: Let $v$ and $w$ be two differentiable vector fields along the curve $\alpha: I\rightarrow S$, with $|v|=1=|w|$. Then $\left[\frac{\text{Dw}}{dt}\right] - \left[\frac{\text{Dv}}{dt}\right] = \frac{d\phi}{dt}$,

where $\left[\frac{\text{Dw}}{dt}\right]$ is the algebraic value of the covariant derivative of $w$ at $t$, and $\phi$ is one of the differentiable determinations of the angle from $v$ to $w$.

The beginning of the proof goes like this (where parenthesis denote the scalar product):

> Proof: We first prove the Lemma for $\phi\neq 0$.
>   Since $(v,w)=\cos\phi$ we obtain
>   $(v',w)+(v,w')=-\sin(\phi)\phi'$
>   hence 
>   $\left(\frac{\text{Dw}}{dt}, w\right) + \left(v, \frac{\text{Dw}}{dt}\right) = \sin(\phi)\phi'$.

I realise, that $v$ and $w$ are differentiable vector fields along the curve $\alpha$, so they are both correspondence maps assigning to each $t$ a vector in the tangentspace of the surface at the points of $\alpha(t)$.

And as the covariant derivative of $v$ at $t$ is the normal projection of the derivative of $v$ at $t$ onto the tangent plane of S at $t$, then howcome the derivative of $v$ is not equal to its covariant derivative? In other words, why is it not simply an equality such as
$v'=\frac{\text{Dw}}{dt}$, which holds in this case?

I would like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $\left(\frac{Dv}{dt},w\right) = \left(\frac{dv}{dt},w\right)$ because $w$ is a (tangent) vector field. Remember that $Dv/dt$ and $dv/dt$ differ only by a vector *normal* to the surface.

Comment: I completely agree in exactly that equality, but howcome the sign difference between the two right hand sides (that is: the $-\sin(\phi)\phi'$ and $\sin(\phi)\phi'$)?

Comment: Oh, that's clearly a stupid typo. By the way, you might find my differential geometry text (linked in my profile) more readable than doCarmo. It doesn't cover quite everything in his text, however.

Comment: Hmmm... Suppose it is a typo, then I have a follow-up question. The entire proof is filled with typographic mistakes (which is in stark contrast to the rest of the book). In case you have a copy of it, the proof can be found on p. 254 (and if you do not, I have found it in google.books under a search of its title)

It seems O.K. up to the point, where he writes
>It follows that $([Dv/dt] - [Dw/dt])\sin(\phi) = \sin(\phi)\phi'$,

Now, if the right hand side actually is negative, I suppose it is on the same form as he originally writes the Lemma (with [Dw/dt] - [Dv/dt]). Is this correct?

Comment: This page does not show up on google.books, and I have only the first edition of the book. By the way, there's also a typo in what you posted. I assume that this one is *your* fault. The first inner product after "Hence" should be $(Dv/dt,w)$.

Comment: Ahh yes, that one is my own.

I apologise for the inconvenience, but if you would like to check up, I found the book here:

https://books.google.dk/books?id=uXF6DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Manfredo+Do+Carmo&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSroq0-4vnAhVvo4sKHebVCWMQ6AEITjAE#v=onepage&q=Manfredo%20Do%20Carmo&f=false

I think it is correct, that Do Carmo had a typo (unless there is some change of orientation, which is not described). The conclusion of his proof then writes
$([Dv/dt] - [Dw/dt])\sin(\phi) = -\sin(\phi)\phi'$
which simplifies to the same form, as he originally wrote the lemma.(..)

Comment: Is this correct? I think that would conclude this question if so. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're going to have to type it yourself. The needed page is missing from that link, too. Either that, or just sort it out correctly yourself.